# How does a staircase switch work?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, electrical-engineering

Well, I live in a descent old kind of house with old wiring and connections but a fascinating thing in my house is a 2 way switch (I don't even know if it is called so).
The arrangement is like we have 2 switch for same lamp and when they are in same position (both ON or both OFF) the bulb glows    otherwise don't.
I want to know the circuit diagram of the composition and how it works.
I know that there are no transistors or capacitors or inductors but just straight wire connection  and it's amazing.

Comment: look for 3-way switch. Wiki page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching with this nice diagram https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/3-way_switches_position_2.svg/450px-3-way_switches_position_2.svg.png

Comment: @Philip: this question is probably off-topic, to be done at "electrical engineering" site https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on DIY.SE

Comment: sorry everyone but I'm new to this site    .. I just made this account few days back   and i didn't knew that HERE THEORITICAL PHYSICS IS ONLY CONSIDERED  not applied sciences and physics      .. and THANKS FOR TELLING ME ABOUT THIS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image][image][image][image]

These are diagrams describing positions in what is called the common system, or traveler system that you seem to be describing. Images from Wikipedia; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching#Traveler_system

Comment: thank you so much sir for the response..  it was really helpful....